# Destructor's Output

Tags: c++, class, destructor

Here is my code

In file Burrito.cpp

```
#include "Burrito.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Burrito::Burrito(){}

void Burrito::printCrap(){cout<< "something"<<endl;}

void Burrito::constante() const{cout<<"this aint gonna change"<<endl;}

Burrito::~Burrito(){cout<<"deconstructed"<<endl;}
```

in file Burrito.h

```
#ifndef BURRITO_H
#define BURRITO_H

class Burrito
{public:
        Burrito();
        void printCrap();
        void constante() const;
        ~Burrito();};

#endif // BURRITO_H
```

And in the main file main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Burrito.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Burrito so;
    Burrito *sagar = &so;
    so.printCrap();
    sagar->printCrap();
  const Burrito constObject;
    constObject.constante();
    return 0;
}
```

I am a beginner and here is my query. I trying to learn about desctructor and this code is performing fine except that it is running the destructor 2 times so the outcome of this program is this:

```
something
something
this aint gonna change
deconstructed
deconstructed
```

Why is it showing "deconstrcuted" two times?

Comment: Because you constructed two `Burrito` objects. Would you expect more or less than 2 destructor calls?

Comment: You've defined two Burrito instances - so and constObject; thus, the destructor (note: destructor, not "deconstructor") is called once for each instance. Best of luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined two objects of the class

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Burrito.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Burrito so;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
    Burrito *sagar = &so;
    so.printCrap();
    sagar->printCrap();

  const Burrito constObject;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    constObject.constante();
    return 0;
}
```

So these two objects are destructed. Neither other objects of the class were created in the program.

The declaration of the pointer `sagar`

```
Burrito *sagar = &so;
```

does not create an object of the class. The pointer refers to the already created object `so`.

Numerous pointers can refer to the same object simultaneously but the object will be destroyed only once.

If you wrote for example

```
Burrito *sagar = new Burrito;
```

and then

```
delete sagar;
```

then in the declaration of the variable `sagar` there is created one more object of the class. and then using operator `delete` it can be deleted. In this case the destructor for the object will be called.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating 2 instances of `Burrito()`.

One is `Burrito so;`
The other one is `const Burrito constObject;`

So, they are destructed when program finishes.

That's why you are getting the output two times.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined two Burrito instances - so and constObject; thus, the destructor (note: destructor, not "deconstructor") is called once for each instance.

To make it clear exactly which object is being created, manipulated, and destroyed you might want to modify your class to include a `name` field, just for demonstration purposes:

### Burrito.h

```
#ifndef BURRITO_H
#define BURRITO_H

class Burrito
{private: char *name;
 public:
        Burrito(char *nm);
        void printCrap();
        void constante() const;
        ~Burrito();};

#endif // BURRITO_H
```

### Burrito.cpp

```
#include "Burrito.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Burrito::Burrito(char *nm){ name = nm; cout << "constructed " << name << endl;}

void Burrito::printCrap(){cout<< name << ": something"<<endl;}

void Burrito::constante() const{cout<< name << ": this aint gonna change"<<endl;}

Burrito::~Burrito(){cout<<"destroyed " << name <<endl;}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Burrito.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Burrito so("so");
    Burrito *sagar = &so;
    so.printCrap();
    sagar->printCrap();
  const Burrito constObject("constObject");
    constObject.constante();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running the above results in:

```
constructed so
so: something
so: something
constructed constObject
constObject: this aint gonna change
destroyed constObject
destroyed so
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have the object `constObject` destroyed at the end of the main AND the `so` object, both are destroyed so they both print this message.